# Leer todo y después ejecutar

Tags: java, archivo

Hola a todos muy buenas tardes, Lo que quiero saber es como hago para poder leer todo el archivo txt y si encuentro una palabra se sigue ejecutando el código y si no se sale.
ejemplo:

```
File archivoFuente = new File ("C:/carpeta/Archivo.txt");
                FileReader fr = new FileReader (archivoFuente);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                FileWriter archivoMaquina = new FileWriter("C:/carpeta/NUEVO_Archivo.txt");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(archivoMaquina);

while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
    linea = linea.trim();
    if(linea.contains("ESTO")){
        /*RESTO DEL CODIGO*/
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Error no contiene ESTO");
    }
}
```

ejemplo de archivoCORRECTO txt:

```
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
ESTO
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
ESTO
Letras y mas letras
```

ejemplo de archivoINCORRECTO txt:

```
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
Letras y mas letras
```

mi problema esta en que primero quiero saber si el archivo contiene mi palabra CLAVE que que en este ejemplo seria **ESTO** ya que de la forma en que tengo mi código lee linea por linea y me da una salida similar a:

```
Error no contiene ESTO
Error no contiene ESTO
Error no contiene ESTO
Error no contiene ESTO
Error no contiene ESTO
Error no contiene ESTO
ESTO
Error no contiene ESTO
Error no contiene ESTO
Error no contiene ESTO
ESTO
Error no contiene ESTO
```

cuando lo que pretendo es que lea todo el archivo primero y determine si la palabra **ESTO** esta o no en el texto, y que solo me diga una sola vez:

```
Error no contiene ESTO
```

y no por cada linea que voy leyendo. espero que mi pregunta se pueda entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pon tu código de la siguiente manera, sólo agregué una variable booleana la cuál determina si debe seguir leyendo en caso de que tenga la clave, o si se detiene en caso de que no tenga la clave.

```
File archivoFuente = new File ("C:/carpeta/Archivo.txt");
                FileReader fr = new FileReader (archivoFuente);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                FileWriter archivoMaquina = new FileWriter("C:/carpeta/NUEVO_Archivo.txt");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(archivoMaquina);
boolean contiene=false;
while((linea=br.readLine())!=null && !contiene){
    linea = linea.trim();
    if(linea.contains("ESTO")){
    contiene=true;
    }
}

if(contiene)
System.out.println("El archivo Contiene esto");
else
System.out.println("El archivo no contiene esto");
```

Comment: ¿Está seguro que funciona su programa como el `OP` lo desea? Evalúa todas las líneas o solo la primera en caso de no encontrar la palabra `"ESTO"`

Comment: Tienes razón, había entendido mal, he corregido el código.

Answer (score 1):

Primero podrías tener una variable `booleana` que le diga el estado de sí está o no está la palabra buscada. si está cambiamos el estado a `true` el estado par no seguir el `while`.

Además se hace uso de [try-Resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) para dejar de "lado" la preocupación de cerrar luego los archivos.

```
 String linea="";
 boolean existe=false;
 try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./archivo.txt"))) {
 while((linea=br.readLine())!=null && !existe){
     if(linea.trim().contains("ESTO")){
      isOrNot=true;
     }
  }
 System.out.println("EL ARCHIVO " + ((existe)?"SI ": "NO") + " CONTIENE ESTO");
   }
}
```